# What can be the reason of a TCP Server connection failure?

Tags: sockets, tcp, mqtt, plc, codesys

I am trying to connect a Wago PFC200 controller to the mosquitto broker I have running on my laptop using the MQTT_Client library by Stefan Rossmann Engineering Solutions.

I get "Connecting to TCP-Server Timed out" error and I'm having trouble figuring out how to troubleshoot it. Before running out of ideas I've tried forcing a bigger value of timeout during runtime, changing the port I'm trying to connect to or the IP — switching to HiveMQ's public MQTT broker, a broker running on my phone and on another laptop. Not sure if that's relevant, but I'm working in e!cockpit.

The socket is created successfully and then the error occurs because `xResult := SysSockConnect(diSocket, ADR(sockAddr), SIZEOF(sockAddr));` does not change to True — why exactly may that be?

```
IF (sockAddr.sin_addr = 0) THEN
        sockAddr.sin_family := SOCKET_AF_INET; 
        IF (right(i_sBrokerAddress,1) = '0' OR right(i_sBrokerAddress,1) = '1' OR right(i_sBrokerAddress,1) = '2' OR right(i_sBrokerAddress,1) = '3' OR right(i_sBrokerAddress,1) = '4'
            OR right(i_sBrokerAddress,1) = '5' OR right(i_sBrokerAddress,1) = '6' OR right(i_sBrokerAddress,1) = '7' OR right(i_sBrokerAddress,1) = '8' OR right(i_sBrokerAddress,1) = '9') THEN
            sockAddr.sin_addr := SysSockInetAddr(i_sBrokerAddress); 
        ELSE
            sockAddr.sin_addr := SysSockGetHostByName(i_sBrokerAddress);
            
            
        END_IF
    END_IF
     
    sockAddr.sin_port :=  SysSockHtons(i_uiPort);
    wTimeOutValue:=1000;
    xResult := SysSockConnect(diSocket, ADR(sockAddr), SIZEOF(sockAddr));
    q_sDiagMsg:='Connect to TCP-Server';
    IF (xResult) THEN
        q_udiState:=15; 
    END_IF
    IF (TON_TimeOut.Q) THEN
        q_udiState:=90; 
        q_xError := TRUE;
        q_sDiagMsg:='Connecting to TCP-Server Timed out';
    END_IF
```

Comment: A quick look with Wireshark would probably reveal the reason or at least give a hint where to look.

Comment: A timeout of one second for a connect is far too short. Raise it.